# variable initialization error c++

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode, initialization

Working on some code using arrays, however I keep getting the error "variable sized object may not be initialized" for the variables in the array even though I initialize them as 0 in the lines before. Here is a piece of my code where the error is.

```
int main(){
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int items[x][y] = {}; //Here is where I get the error
for(string food; cin >> food; x++)
{
    items[x] = food;
    if(food == "done")
        cout << "Thank you for inputting.\n";
}
for(double price; cin >>price; y++)
{
    items[y] = price;
    if(price == 0)
    {
        double total;
        total += price;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: 4 things: 1. Make your array size initializer variables `const`. 2. You cannot initialize an array of size `0` 3. The array size doesn't increase _magically_ as you increment `x` or `y`. 4. Use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` and `push_back()` to let them grow dynamically.

Comment: You seem to have written this code using a random number generator - just about every line is wrong. Please read a book on C++ rather than guessing.

Comment: Also variable length arrays are rigid and non standard, consider `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead.

Comment: You're actually looking for a map associating a price to a string value entered, right?

Comment: If the `items` has size `x`, then you can only access the range 0 to x-1.  `items[x]` is out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int items[x][y] = {};
```

defines a variable length array `items`, which is not supported in C++ standard, but only in particular extensions. To overcome this, you'd have to declare `x` and `y` as `const` (and with a value > 0, obviously).

But I think you're using the wrong data structure, since it seems that you want to associate a price with the name of a fruit. A `map<string,double>` is better suited for this task:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main(){
    std::string food;
    std::map<std::string,double> priceForFood;
    std::cout << "enter food and price or quit to finish:" << std::endl;
    while(std::cin >> food && food != "quit") {
        double price;
        if (std::cin >> price) {
            priceForFood[food]=price;
        }
    }
    for (auto pair : priceForFood) {
        std::cout << pair.first << " cost " << pair.second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
enter food and price or quit to finish:
apples 100
oranges 200
quit
```

Output:

```
apples cost 100
oranges cost 200
Program ended with exit code: 0
```